# Menu Toggleable Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>PrimeFaces</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body class="body">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
        <p:layout fullPage="true">


            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Header
            </p:layoutUnit>


            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="150" collapsible="false" style="width: 150px">
                <p:menu  toggleable="true" style="width: 128px; bottom: 2px">
                    <p:submenu label="Cadastros" >
                        <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu >
                <p:menu toggleable="true">
                    <p:submenu label="Cadastros"  >
                        <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>

            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                Welcome to PrimeFaces
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

Porém quando adiciono a tag `<p:menu toggleable="true">` ele diz que não existe `toggleable` para menu.

Esse é o exemplo do site de demos do *Primeface*.

```
<p:menu toggleable="true">
    <p:submenu label="Ajax">
        <p:menuitem value="Save" actionListener="#{menuView.save}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{menuView.update}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax">
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{menuView.delete}" update="messages" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Navigations">
        <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Internal" outcome="/mobile/index" icon="ui-icon-star"/>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

Estou usando a versão 6.1 do *Primefaces*.

Por que no meu código não reconhece esta tag?

Comment: Não precisa estar dentro de um `<h:form>`?

Comment: Esse menu não. Mais eu testei com <h:form> e deu na mesma.

Comment: Posta a mensagem de erro por favor

Comment: Achei a solução do problema. Acho que era algum bug do Netbeans. Eu exclui o arquivo .jar reimportei para o projeto depois cliquei em Clean and Build. Depois destes passos ele achou a Tag toggleable